# How to make image align with input element

Tags: html, css

Update after implementing the code adding its on div

[image]

How can I make the image sit next to City input element?

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="assetList">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:45% !important;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">                         Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:35% !important;">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">                         City</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
                        <a class="action-image remove-action" href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <img alt="Remove" title="Remove" src="delete.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your style:

```css
.form-group {
  positon: relative;
}
.remove-action {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -4px;
}
```

Comment: actually your css worked, i have to adjust the right position - thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Of course you have to see it in full page to see the effect**

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position:relative;  
}

.remove-action {
  position:absolute;
  right:5px;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-sm-12" id="assetList">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 45% !important;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 35% !important;">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
                <a class="action-image remove-action" href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <img alt="Remove" title="Remove" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagona/icon/16/101.png">
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

To make the `x` icon in the middle of the input, you need to wrap the input with `.input-wrapper` with `position:relative;`.

The trick is to use (for the icon):

```
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```css
.input-has-icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-has-icon .form-control {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.input-has-icon .action-image,
.icon-after-input .action-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.icon-after-input {
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.icon-after-input .action-image {}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-12" id="assetList">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:45% !important;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:35% !important;">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-has-icon">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
          <a class="action-image remove-action" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img alt="Remove" title="Remove" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/16/Delete.png">
          </a>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="col-sm-12" id="assetList">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:45% !important;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="width:35% !important;">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="icon-after-input">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
          <a class="action-image remove-action" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img alt="Remove" title="Remove" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/16/Delete.png">
          </a>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add an extra div before your input tag and style it this way.