# Add icon inside a search input tag?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```css
    body { background: #666; }

    #header-search {
      width: 200px;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      font-size: 12pt;
      border: 0px solid;
      outline: 0;
      vertical-align: -50%;
    }
    
    #header-search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: white;
    }
    
    #search-field svg {
        fill: white;
        width: 30px;
        heigth: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="search-field">
     <input type="search" id="header-search" placeholder="Search..." />
     <svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
         <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
         <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
     </svg>
    </div>
```

I want to have the SVG icon last in the search input field, how can i do that? What i get right now is that the icon is outside and that is pretty ugly.

Comment: Add the SVG as an image and then it to be the background of the input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make image align with input element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203858/how-to-make-image-align-with-input-element)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203858/how-to-make-image-align-with-input-element/34203989#34203989 - Similar Question, already asked and answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `relative` `position`ing on your icon.

Adjust `right` to accomodate its width in order to shift it to left, so that it appears inside the `input`. Adjust `vertical-align` to keep it in middle. Don't forget enough `padding-right` on the `input` to prevent text overflow into the icon.

```
#search-icon { position: relative; right: 28px; }
```

**Snippet:**

```css
#header-search {
  display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 32px;
  background: black; color: white; border: none; outline: none;
  font-size: 12pt; padding: 4px 28px 4px 4px; vertical-align: middle;
}
#search-icon {
  position: relative; right: 28px;
  fill: white; width: 24px; height: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-field">
  <input type="search" id="header-search" placeholder="Search..." />
  <svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go .

Give `#search-field svg` to `absolute` position and `#search-field` to position `relative`

```css
#header-search {
  width: 200px;
  background: @header-color;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border: 0px solid;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: -50%;
  height: 44px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

#header-search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: black;
}

#search-field svg {
  fill: red;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
}
#search-field{display: inline-block; position: relative}
```

```html
<div id="search-field">
  <input type="search" id="header-search" placeholder="Search..." />
  <svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z" />
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Cant get this working here above, changed more than just added position: relative and absolute ? plus inline-block; ?

Comment: You might miss this 

#search-field svg {
  fill: red;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0;
}

Here, the top and right positions the search icon.

Comment: The icon is now in wrong element i see, its just below the "search-field" not inside it?

Comment: This is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p4hnuq4x/ please go through it. tell me if you face any problem.

Comment: Apart from all, I have given height 44px for #header-search.

Comment: Why 44px? Why not for example 40 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98570/discussion-between-jinu-kurian-and-mikael).

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute`

```css
body { background: #666; }

    #header-search {
      width: 200px;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      font-size: 12pt;
      border: 0px solid;
      outline: 0;
      vertical-align: -50%;
    }
    
    #header-search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: white;
    }
    #search-field { position:relative; display:inline-block;}
    
    #search-field svg {
        fill: white;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
      right: 10px;
      z-index:200;
    }
```

```html
<div id="search-field">
     <input type="search" id="header-search" placeholder="Search..." />
     <svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
         <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
         <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
     </svg>
    </div>
```